# How to retrieve last record of each category( faster way )

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, query-performance, sql-tuning

I use Oracle as DBMS and have a large table(400,000,000 records). Now, I want to retrieve the last record of each category. When I use "group by" as shown below, it takes a long time. Is there a faster way?

Note: I need to retrieve all the table's data:

```
select * 
from myTable tb1
inner join 
    (select MAX(id) max_id, categoryColumn 
     from myTable 
     group by categoryColumn) tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.max_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by categoryColumn order by id desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I would recommend an index on `(categoryColumn, id desc)`.

With this index, you might find that the correlated subquery is faster:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
              from mytable t2
              where t2.categoryColumn = t.categoryColumn
             );
```

Although I think the above are faster, I have had good performance using `keep`.  The syntax is more cumbersome:

```
select categoryColumn, max(id) as id,
       max(col1) keep (dense_rank first order by id desc) as col1,
       max(col2) keep (dense_rank first order by id desc) as col2,
       . . .  -- and so on for each column
from mytable t
group by categoryColumn;
```

Comment: TNX Gordon. I executed above scripts for 1000000 records, but "JOIN" is faster. is there another way that be faster?

Comment: @Yaser . . . Do you have the recommended index?

Comment: I created index on 'categoryColumn' and 'id' columns sepratly. When i changed that_(categoryColumn, id desc) as an index_ , correlated subquery is better(12% to 25%). TNX a lot.